# Set Text Field By Radio Choice

Tags: javascript, radio-button, textfield

This is my first real attempt to write a JS function. I want to set the value of a text field depending on the selction of a pair of radio buttons.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function setInputValue(){

if(document.getElementById('choice_8_0').checked) {

       document.getElementById('input_6_18').value = '1';

    }else if(document.getElementById('choice_8_1').checked) {

     document.getElementById('input_6_18').value = '0';
}}

</script>
```

Can anyone help me with where I went wrong? I am not even sure how to name the function really.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your html as well which is invoking this function?

Comment: You can see form on this page hookahi.com/guides/hucks-charters/

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
 document.getElementById('elementId').checked = true;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('elementId').checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

To select a radiobutton, you can use the `checked` property of the radiobutton:

```
 document.getElementById('input_6_18').checked = true/false;
```

EDIT: seems like you want to set the text of an input type text?

Than your code is correct, the property is `value`. So what is the problem?

Comment: I think the if condition is already ensuring that whether the checkbox(which is with id '#choice_8_x' ) checked or not

Comment: Yes, i thought he wanted to set the value of another radio button.. but i don't know what his question really is, to be honest..

Comment: My fault for now clarifying. The input_6_18 box is a standard text field. Depending on which radio button is selected I would like to automatically fill the text field with either 0 or 1

Comment: At this point the problem is simply that nothing is happening when I select the radio buttons. That's why I sought help

Comment: Please post all of your code, also where do you call this function?

Comment: That is pretty much the exact code above, I added the true/false in as was suggested, here is exact code: http://pastie.org/5437096 , the code is in the <head></head> tags

Comment: but where exactly do you call the function?